# как умножить числа в массиве парами

Tags: javascript

```
x=[1,7,5,3]
for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){}
```

Допустим есть массив из чисел, у которых`ёlength` 4 или больше, скажем:6, нужно умножить их парами, например, первый элемент со вторым, третий с четвёртым, а пятый с  шестым

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [1, 7, 5, 3];
var result = x.reduce((acc, cur, i, src) => {
  return i % 2 === 0 ? acc.concat(src[i] * src[i + 1]) : acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    x=[1,7,5,3];
    let newArr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            let temp = x[i] * x[i+1];
            newArr.push(temp);
        }
    }
    console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mult = (a, b) => a * b
const log = (...q) => console.log(...q)

x = [2, 3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 99]
while ([a, b] = x.splice(0, 2), b) log(mult(a, b))
if (a&&!b) log(a)
```